# Create a handsontable in ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I would like to use a handsontable inside a `ng-switch`: when we select `handsontable`, it shows a normal and editable handsontable.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/riyiges/3/edit?html,js,output)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <select ng-model="myVar">
    <option value="dogs">Dogs
    <option value="handsontable">handsontable
  </select>

  <div ng-switch="myVar">
    <div ng-switch-when="dogs">
     <p>Welcome to a world of dogs.</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="handsontable">
      <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');
var settings1 = { data: [['A1', 'B1'], ['A2', 'B2']] };
var hot1 = new Handsontable(example1, settings1);
```

Unlike [this working example](https://jsbin.com/fujupihabu/edit?html,js,output), the cells in the table are NOT editable. So I am wondering if there is something missing. For example in the working example, the creation of the table is wrapped by `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { ... })`, should I wrap the javascript code in this example by something to make sure we create the table only after we ng-switch to `handsontable`?

Comment: Have a look to [`ngHandsontable`](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @Mistailis suggested, we could use `ngHandsontable`.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/riyiges/5/edit?html,js,output)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">
  <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <script src="../dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <select ng-model="myVar">
    <option value="dogs">Dogs
    <option value="handsontable">handsontable
  </select>

  <div ng-switch="myVar">
    <div ng-switch-when="dogs">
     <p>Welcome to a world of dogs.</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="handsontable">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
        <hot-table datarows="ctrl.db.items"></hot-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function dataFactory () { };
dataFactory.$inject = [];
angular.module('ngHandsontable').service('dataFactory', dataFactory);

function MainCtrl(dataFctory) {
  this.db = { items: [[5, 6], [7, 8]] };
}
MainCtrl.$inject = ['dataFactory'];

angular
  .module('app', ['ngHandsontable'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```